# CSS inline-block Positioning Issue

Tags: html, layout, css

I'm trying to make a website and I'm having some problems at layout.
I want `div:logo` and `div:social media` to be at the same line but I couldn't do.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uEL9d/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

write your div:logo and div:social media like this (side by side)
don't make any space between them

```
<div class="child" id="logo">logo</div><div class="child" id="socialMedia">sosyal media</div>
```

hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: this is more of a hack rather than a solution. The correct solution has been given by abhishek Jain

Comment: I have read it. The OP wants the div's on the same line, this can easily be tackled with a bit of CSS. The solution you have suggested is a 'HACK'. It should definitely not be used in real world scenarios are is not indented code.

Comment: @AnaMaria, it isn't a hack, it's just understanding how the use of display inline and inline-block changes how elements are treated and interact with other elements around them.  If you have a look at the fiddle in my example, you are able to keep pretty much all your indentation

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

HTML:

```
        <div class="parent">
            <div class="parent" id="header">
                <div class="child floatL" id="logo" >
                    logo
                </div>
                <div class="child floatL" id="socialMedia" >
                    sosyal media
                </div>
                <div class="child" id="menuBar">
                    menu bar
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="parent" id="body">
                body
            </div>

            <div class="parent" id="footer">
                footer
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}

.floatL
{
    float:left;
}

.parent {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 960px;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
}

.parent, .child {
    border:  none;
    background-color: #CCC;
}

#logo {
    width: 640px;
    background-color: #ff6a00;
}

#socialMedia {
    width: 320px;
    background-color: #ffd800;
}

#menuBar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #b6ff00;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uEL9d/2/)

Comment: thanks, this works but is there any way to do without using float?

Comment: Try this: <div class="child floatL" id="logo" >logo</div><div class="child floatL" id="socialMedia" >sosyal media</div>  But i will say not a very good practice

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `display:inline-block` you are unable to have a space between your inline-block elements otherwise it will treat this as a whitespace and insert it.

Remove this and it will work:

[White space between divs deleted](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/uEL9d/3/)

[Indentation of code kept with comments](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/uEL9d/4/)